# How to name a transport layer class?

Tags: c#, class, naming-conventions, classname, transport

I've got a class which deals only with messages from other classes. It handles their events, queues argument message, consumes it from an appropriate thread and sends it to another class. Thread creating/cancelling is also on his conscience.

It might be a popular pattern, so it might be a conventional naming. English is not my first language, so I have a problem.

Comment: I would suggest InteractionManager because the class manages the object interactions.

Comment: Quite exotic, isn't it? I can't find any example of this name

Comment: Exotic names are more likely to be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

The mediator behavioural pattern sounds like this.

Comment: Yes, it is mediator (as far as I've understood it right now), but the main point is in the cross-threading. This class keeps a thread with a queue for each user and routes messages to the right thread by using cons/prod pattern